# How to add param to form adf

Tags: action, oracle-adf

I have a jsff page.

In this, I define a `<af:form id="f1"></af:form>`

How do I add parameter to action attribute in this form?

I used `<f:param ... />` tag inner this form:

```
<af:form id="f1">
<f:param value="#{param.id}" name="id"/>
...
</af:form>
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a parameter. Do that in the commandButton/commandLink. Or else you could pass a attribute to the form.

#### Passing a parameter

```
   <af:commandLink text="click here"
                                    action="#{testbean.buttonClicked}" >
                                    <f:param name="et1" value="etc"/> 
                                    </af:commandLink>
```

#### Access it In the Bean

```
   FacesContext facesContext= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   Map requestMap=facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
```

Or

#### Passing an Attribute

```
<af:form id="f1" binding="#{testbean.form}">
<f:attribute name="et1" value="etc"/>
```

#### In the Bean

**In Action Method**

```
String value2=(String)form.getAttributes().get("et1");
```

Or best yet use

**af:setPropertyListener**

#### In the command component

```
 <af:commandLink text="click here"
                                action="#{testbean.buttonClicked}" >
   <af:setPropertyListener type="action" from="etc" to="#{et1}"/>
   </af:commandLink>
```

#### In the Bean on action method

```
 String value3=(String)evaluateEL("#{et1}");
```

Answer (score 0):

put a button or link or ... in your form and use:

```
    <af:setActionListener from="value" to="#{...Scope.yourParam}"/>
```

"..." can be SessionScope,pageFlowScope,etc